# How do I create a more efficient portrait gallery using Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, gallery, ccsprite, parallax

I'm building an app that has gallery of portraits (like a museum) and my character(s) walk past them from left-to-right-to-left.  My portrait (images) are all 2048x2048.  I haven't reduced their size yet because I want to make sure they can be used for the iPad version. I know their large size is an issue because it crashes when I try to load all of them at once (and it takes a long time to launch even with only 10 images).

That being said, my real issue is trying to create an efficient method for adding/removing them (sprites) as needed.  I came up with something that works but it is clearly not the best way to do this.

I am hoping someone can suggest a more efficient approach.

Here is my code.  You can assume another method takes care of loading the images into a mutable array called framedSprites (except I can only load 10 at a time because of the size/crashing).  The following method (checkPosition) is called every time the screen position changes (via a TouchMoved swipe).  As I see it, I will have to create similar statements for each image/portrait in the array (very inefficient and time consuming)...

```
-(void)checkPosition {

CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;

for (CCSprite *sprite in framedSprites) {

    if (sprite.tag == 2) {

        if ((sprite.position.x > 2000.0f)&&(sprite.position.x < 2010.0f)) {

            CCSprite *portrait = (CCSprite *)[_backgroundNode getChildByTag:0];

            if (portrait.tag == 0) {

                NSLog(@"Removing a Portrait Left 2 Places From This One");

                 [_backgroundNode removeChildByTag:0 cleanup:YES];

            }
        }

        if ((sprite.position.x > 1980.0f)&&(sprite.position.x < 1990.0f)) {

            CCSprite *portrait = (CCSprite *)[_backgroundNode getChildByTag:0];

            if (portrait == nil) {

                CCSprite * framedSprite = (CCSprite *)[framedSprites objectAtIndex:0];

                NSLog(@"Adding a Portrait Left, 2 Places From This One");

                framedSprite.position = ccp(600,winSize.height/2);  //figuring these positions is also not efficient and time consuming

                [_backgroundNode addChild:framedSprite z:0 parallaxRatio:ccp(0.4f,0.5f) positionOffset:framedSprite.position];

            }
        } 
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to have 3 images loaded at any one time to allow scrolling in either direction (assuming you're not also allowing movement in the y direction). The one on display, one either side as a buffer and then lazy load and replace as needed.

If you don't need to see the entire image at once you could also consider cutting it into tiles using a free tool like Tilen (http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/tilen/id409199185?mt=12) and then loading the tiles as required.

Comment: I understand the principle you are recommending but not clear on how to implement it efficiently.  Doing it one-by-one doesn't appear very efficient.  Isn't there a way to do it with a for loop or something?

Comment: Maintain an array of your images and then depending on the direction you are travelling remove the item from the opposite end of the array and push a new item on the other end. i.e 3 items if going left <- pop the last item off you array (and clean up after it) and add a new item at position[0] in the array.

There's going to be a trade off between loading (& decompressing time) and memory usage. 

With Cocos2d use png's not jpg's if loading speed is an issue, cocos2d converts jpg's to png's under the hood before doing anything else.

Comment: As you can see from my code posted above, I am pretty much already doing what you are suggesting.  My issue is that I have to manually check each sprite (there are 100 to check!) each time the character moves and know exactly where they are in order to determine which ones to add/remove. There must be a better way.